# Folding two lists in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, fold

How do I fold two tensors using tensorflow? `tensorflow.foldl` takes as input

- a function of type `a, b -> a` (Here `a` and `b` represents the type of tensors of a particular shape)
- a Tensor that can be unpacked into a list `[b]` of entries of type `b`
- an initial accumulator of type `a`

I need a function that takes as input

- a function of type `a, b, c -> a`
- a Tensor that can be unpacked into a list `[b]` of entries of type `b`
- a Tensor that can be unpacked into a list `[c]` of entries of type `c`
- an initial accumulator of type `a`.

Comment: Have you tried chaining them? i.e. `fold(fold(a,b), c)`?

Comment: That doesn't work because it's equivalent to folding over the concatenation of b and c.

Answer (score 0):

Use *concat* and *transpose* and fold over 0 dimension, but it will work only for same types. Example:

```
data_x = [[i for i in range(1,11)]]
data_y = [[10*i for i in range(1,11)]]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1,10))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1,10))
c = tf.constant(100.)

cn = tf.concat([x,y], axis=0)
t = tf.transpose(cn)
f = tf.foldl(lambda a,y: a+y[0]+y[1], t, c)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  res = sess.run(t, feed_dict={x: data_x, y: data_y})
  print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def fold2(f, li1, li2, init):
    (_, a1) = tf.while_loop(lambda i, a: i<tf.shape(li1)[0], lambda i, a: (i+1, f(a, li1[i], li2[i])), (0,init))
    return a1
```

Incidentally, this also works with TensorArray's, while `tf.foldl` does not.